# How to make a piece on checkboard to move either left or right?

Tags: c

So far, the program that I have initializes and prints the checkboard as it is supposed to. Here are both **init** and **print** functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void initBoard(int n, int board[n][n]){

int i, j;
int numberOfRows = n/2 - 1;

for(i=0; i<numberOfRows; i++){
    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
        if((i%2==0&&j%2==0)||(i%2==1&&j%2==1)){
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }else{
            board[i][j] = -1;
        }

        board[numberOfRows][j] = 0;
        board[numberOfRows+1][j] = 0;
    }
}

for(i=numberOfRows+2;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if((i%2==0&&j%2==0)||(i%2==1&&j%2==1)){
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }else{
            board[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
}

}

void printBoard(int n, int board[n][n]){

int i, j;

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(board[i][j]==0){
            board[i][j] = '-';
        }else if(board[i][j]==1){
            board[i][j] = 'W';
        }else{
            board[i][j] = 'D';
        }
        printf("%3c", board[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

}
```

However, implementation of ***move*** function (provided example is for only right direction) which should move pieces on the board seem to not work.

```
void move(int n, int board[n][n], int x, int y, char direction){

if(direction!='R'||direction!='L'){
    printf("\nYou can move only to right or left.\n\n");
}else if(direction=='R'){

    if(x==n-1){
        printf("You cannot move the piece to the right because you are already in a right corner of the board.\n");
    }else{
        if(board[y][x]==0){
            printf("There is no piece in the column %i and row %i.\n", x, y);
        }else if(board[y][x]==1){
            if(y==0){
                printf("You are on the kings row! Further move cannot be made.\n");
            }else{
                if(board[n-2-y][x+1]!=0){
                    printf("You cannot move in the following direction because there is already a piece in that cell.\n");
                }else{
                    board[n-1-y][x] = 0;
                    board[n-2-y][x+1] = 1;
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(y==n-1){
                 printf("You are on the kings row! Further move cannot be made.\n");
            }else{
                if(board[n-y][x+1]!=0){
                    printf("You cannot move in the following direction because there is already a piece in that cell.\n");
                }else{
                    board[n-1-y][x] = 0;
                    board[n-y][x+1] = -1;
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

After testing it out, here is the test:

```
int main(){

int size = 8;
int board[size][size];

initBoard(size, board);
printBoard(size, board);

move(size, board, 2, 2, 'R');
printBoard(size, board);

return 0;

}
```

...it shows in the console:

```
-  D  -  D  -  D  -  D //this board is printed w/o any move function.
D  -  D  -  D  -  D  -
-  D  -  D  -  D  -  D
-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
W  -  W  -  W  -  W  -
-  W  -  W  -  W  -  W
W  -  W  -  W  -  W  -

You can move only to right or left.

D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D //this is what happened when move function was called.
D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
```

Comment: Post a complete program, please, compilable and runnable.  The bug could also be in your `printBoard` function or elsewhere in your code.  At a first glance, the mixing of `board[y]` and `board[n-y]`, `board[n-1-y]`, etc, doesn't seem right, but I am not seeing how it would cause the behavior you describe.

Comment: @NateEldredge done.

Answer (score 0):

- The first call to `printBoard` overwrites the contents of `board` with the characters `'D', 'W', '-'`.
- `move` doesn't actually do anything at all to the board, because your test `if(direction!='R'||direction!='L')` is always false.  (The message "You can move only to right or left." should have been a tip-off.)  You probably meant to write `if(direction!='R' && direction!='L')`.  So it is not the cause of the all-`D` output you are seeing.
- So at the second call to `printBoard`, the array `board` is still full of the characters `'D', 'W', '-'`.  But `printBoard` is expecting it to be full of `1,-1,0`.  The way your test is written, anything other than those values falls into the last `else` clause, as if the value were `-1`, and is printed as (and replaced with) `D`.

You probably want to change `printBoard` to be non-destructive, and you'll probably have some more debugging to do on `move` once you have fixed the test to make it actually functional.  I am very suspicious of your mixed `board[y]` and `board[n-1-y]` indices.  You need to make up your mind whether `y` counts rows from the top of the board, or the bottom.

Reminder: always post complete code when asking for help!  In this case, your first guess about which function contained the bug was completely wrong.  Someone could have wasted a lot of time poring over that code in vain.

Another tip: I didn't do anything clever other than single-step your code in a debugger, watching the contents of `board` and seeing where it changed.  I suggest getting familiar with your debugger and using it to try to understand the behavior of your code *before* asking the Internet for help.  (And when you do ask, report what you learned from your debugging session.)